# How to gather a key in between the call using Twilio?

Tags: java, twilio, twilio-twiml

I have a following `TwiML` file :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
 <Response>     
   <Say> Your call is going to transfer the Receptionist </Say>
     <Dial maxLength="180">
        <Number> 442-333-7271 </Number>
        <Gather numDigits = "9" action = "_actionURL" method="GET">
        <Say> Please press 9 </Say>
    </Gather>
    </Dial>
```

According to above code i want to redirect the flow to `_actionURL` if receiver press `9` in between of call.

How should i do it?

Comment: I don't think you can put the `<Gather>` verb inside `<Dial>`

Comment: @socialrel8 then how should i do it?

Comment: Are you getting any errors in the Twilio console on your account page?

Comment: No, but according to above code it connect the call and after completion of call it wait to gather the key. Please see the comment on your answered section

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
 <Response>     
  <Gather numDigits = "9" action = "_actionURL" method="GET">
   <Say> Your call is going to transfer the Receptionist, please press 9 to go somewhere else </Say>
   <Dial maxLength="180">442-333-7271</Dial>
  </Gather>
 </Response>
```

Comment: Thanks for the answering. I can't test it right now but according to your code it will place a call to the number and in between call if someone press the any 9 digit it will redirect the call according to actionURL?

or it will complete the call then it wait for gather the key?

Comment: I can't test it at the moment. So you please test.

Comment: I tried it and here is the response:
It says the above message "your call..." and if i didn't press any key then it ended the call instead of connect to that number and while if i pressed some 9 keys then it redirect to that actionURL. Call is not connecting in any case.

Comment: You may not be able to do it then - I think once the call has started the dial process you can't abort it.

Comment: That's ok but it didn't even make a call. Why is this happening to above your answer.

Comment: It didn't make the call? It could be that `<Dial>` is not allowed inside the `<Gather>` verb then. Check your Twilio console for errors.